# TargetInvocationException thrown when attempting FirstOrDefault on IEnumerable

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, azure

I suspect I'm missing something rather basic, yet I can't figure this one out.

I'm running a simple linq query -

```
var result = from UserLine u in context.Users 
             where u.PartitionKey == provider.Value && u.RowKey == id.Value 
             select u;
        UserLine user = null;
        try
        {
            user = result.FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

For some reason this produces a `TargetInvocationException` with an inner exception of `NullReferenceException`.

This happens when the linq query produces no results, but I was under the impression that `FirstOrDefault` would return `Default<T>` rather than throw an exception?

I don't know if it matters, but the `UserLine` class inherits from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity`

Comment: What do the provider and id objects represent? If instead of them, you put a couple of hardcoded values in the query that will not generate any rows do you still get the same exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the problem occured when either id or provider had '/' in the value, which the id did. when I removed it the code ran fine

[Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx) has a section on 'Characters Disallowed in Key Fields' -

> The following characters are not allowed in values for the
>   PartitionKey and RowKey properties:
>
> - The forward slash (/) character
> - The backslash () character
> - The number sign (#) character
> - The question mark (?) character

Comment: While not mentioned in the documentation, I've also found that the following characters can be used in partition/row keys, but cause problems if you try to delete rows with them in the keys (%) and (�)

Answer (score 1):

there are two possible reasons:

- provider.Value
- id.Value

Are you sure that theese nullables have value. You might want to check HasValue before

```
var result = from UserLine u in context.Users 
             where (provider.HasValue && u.PartitionKey == provider.Value)
                 && (id.HasValue && u.RowKey == id.Value)
             select u;
UserLine user = null;
try
{
    user = result.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Comment: Thanks maxlego, interesting as I've never considered looking at the linq statement (and should have), what I found interesting is taht both id.Value and provider.Value are not null yet, if I remove the where clause this works fine and with it I get the exception. also - each equation on it's own works fine, having both seem to cause a problem for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it produced a different error, but based on the situation in which the problem is occurring you might want to look to check if `context.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException` is set to false?  If it is try setting it to true.

This [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoreresourcenotfoundexception.aspx) is a flag to indicate whether you want the storage library to throw and error when you use both PartitionKey and RowKey in a query and no result is found (it makes sense when you think about what the underlying REST API is doing, but it's a little confusing when you're using LINQ)

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting it to true originally and it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Fair enough, it was a bit of a long shot

Comment: As another idea, are either provider.Value or id.Value null?

Comment: Thanks, but no - I've confirmed that when looking at Maxlego's answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's some fun try putting the where query the other way around like this to see if it works (I heard a while ago it does!):

```
where (id.HasValue && u.RowKey == id.Value) && (provider.HasValue && u.PartitionKey == provider.Value)
```

Other than this you can now set IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true in the TableServiceContext to receive null when an entity is not found instead of the error.

It's a crazy Azure storage thing.

Comment: Thanks BD, as I've mentioned the IgnoreResourceNotFoundException did not work for me, not sure now, now I'm surprised to NOT FIND a HasValue property for 'id' and 'provider', can you think why that might be?